# Allow Bundle Item Qty to 0 in Cart page in magento 1.9

Tags: php, magento-1.9

I want to add a bundle item with 0 qty in cart.

[image: bundle configuration]

In above screentshot of a bundle product, i want "sydney 2 seater" item qty to 0 . but when i add it to cart it's changes to 1
[image: cart page]

I already try with changing min qty to cart to 0,
default qty of bundle item to 0,
didn't work

Comment: I'm not sure this is a bundle, it looks more like a Grouped Product since you've got Qty inputs... but this question would be a better fit on: https://magento.stackexchange.com/

Comment: ... and if it is a bundle, did you specify *Product Information -> Bundle Items -> Is Required -> **No*** ?

Comment: Thanks a lot !!! this i'll create a radio button on front end to choose,but it's okay, i hide those radio buttons,